# Is this possible to do A on B , B on C , C on A with CSS HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

Is this possible to do  A on B , B on C , C on A with CSS HTML and JavaScript?

like this :

[image]

Comment: no, you have to split at least one of these into two parts/layer, where one layer is beneath the stack, and the other (half-one) is above. Like A at the bottom, then B, then C, and then a copy of A, wich is partially masked to only cover the area on top of the stack.

Comment: Lol, you should make your questions more constructive. Is that possible? ..... yes indeed

Comment: But depending on the concrete content of your layer *(only color or background-image)*, you might be able to create this masked copy with CSS and a pseudo-element (`:after`)

Comment: and @FlyingGambit  you  should read questions Carefully

Comment: Thanks for answer @Thomas. so u say it is not possible to break z-index order?

Comment: Afaik. no, because although CSS has got kind of 3D-abilities, afaik. they are only "flat" transformations as a post-processing step per layer. so each DOM-Node is seen individually in this process, and not as part of a bigger 3D-Space.

Comment: Draw the green rect using two rect elements each 1/2 the width. The one on the left would be behind, the one on the right in front. If they are the same colour they will appear to be one. Or apply a clip-path to one of the rects to cut out the piece you want to show through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, only Chrome supports *transform-style: preserve-3d* at the pixel level - instead of at the element level. Since it is done at the pixel level, some parts of the element can rendered in front of another element, and some in back.

```css
body {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.A {
  background-color: tomato;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(3deg);  /* this does the trick */
}

.B {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.C {
  background-color: lightblue;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-120deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">Some fancy text</div>
<div class="B">Some fancy text</div>
<div class="C">Some fancy text</div>
```

So , for the moment, you will be limited to use tricks - basically rendering one of the elements as 2 different elements